# iPhone app: not able to select iOS device or iOS Simulator for running the project

Tags: iphone, ios4, xcode4, ios-simulator

For my iPhone app I am not able to select iOS device or iOS Simulator for running the project it is only showing option for mac-64 bit. What could be wrong?

I am facing this problem after I moved my project from one desktop system to another.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually I facing this problem  beacouse I have renamed the project

I could solve it from

Manage scheme-> Autocreate scheme now

Comment: Thanks ! I was running code from xCode 4.4.1 to 4.3.1. I was getting same problem. your solution is worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your sdk versions differ,
did you try to recreate the project and just import the code.

If this is a one time change that might be working out.

Answer (score 0):

Try going into the project settings, and changing the base SDK to iOS (4.3).

An option for this can be found in the info and build settings panels of the project window. I recommend changing it in both places