# Select simulator or iOS device for testing on Xcode not appearing

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

My Xcode 6.4 isn’t showing up the option next to run button to select any simulator or physical device.

[image]

I know I can select any iOS device or simulator from the below menu but I would love to bring that option back.

[image]

This is discussed here [not able to select ios device or ios Simulator for running the project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6828041/iphone-app-not-able-to-select-ios-device-or-ios-simulator-for-running-the-proje)  but doesn’t reply to my question.
How can I bring that back?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stretching Xcode’s window in horizontal position will solve the problem.

Comment: yeah its true.Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Don't worry.Sometimes it happens. You can resolve by creating new Schema also.