# Xcode not showing product scheme after updating to EL Capitan?

Tags: ios, xcode, osx-elcapitan

I’m using xcode 6.4. it was working fine but after updating to EL Capitan. Now the product scheme is not showing. image attached.

I'm not able to select any device or simulator

[image]

Comment: r u verified once close the xcode and system and restart once

Comment: confirm that you are not using any variant of xcode 6. I also got the same issue with xcode 6.4, but when I used xcode 7 , everything was working fine.

Comment: Why don't you update to Xcode 7.0? It works for me.

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik restart not working..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Confirm that you are not using any variant of `xcode 6`. I also got the same issue with `xcode 6.4`, but when I used `xcode 7`, everything was working fine.

So get `xcode 7`. It will work

Here is a snippet of bug with `OS X El Capitan Developer Beta 7 Release Notes`

[image]

Refer [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/General/rn-osx-10.11/) link for more.

Answer (score 3):

Just stretch the Xcode window in horizontal direction and make it bigger than your screen size, it will bring that back. I had the same issue on Xcode 6.4 and El Capitan.
Check my question and answer [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32901118/select-simulator-or-ios-device-for-testing-on-xcode-not-appearing/32945048#32945048)

Comment: No its not a soluction

Answer (score 2):

I've the same problem. 
If you want continue to work with Xcode 6.x you can select the Scheme and Device on "Product" => "Destination", or "Product" => "Scheme"

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the final solution, but you can goto `Product->Destination` and select the device.

**The ultimate solution is to use XCode 7.**

*P.S - Download from Official Apple source only.*