# scheme and destination tab in XCode

Tags: ios, xcode

The scheme and destination tabs/buttons which are generally located near run and stop buttons in xcode have hidden unexpectedly ,i don't know how to unhide them.
Can someone help.I am using xcode 6.3

[image]

Comment: Have you updated your OS to OS X EI Captian??

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33011834/988169 & http://stackoverflow.com/a/23207699/988169

Comment: Yes I have updated to El Captain

Comment: For EI Captian Xcode 6 versions have some compatibility issues. If u get Xocde 7 this issue will be fixed